# Recreating matlab second order filter in python

Tags: matlab, fft, filters, filter-design, python

I want to create some custom filters in Matlab `filterDesigner` tool and then apply those filters to a large set of audio files. I want to use python to do the application of the filters to the audios.

I created a Butterworth filter in Matlab and exported it as an ASCII file. In there I get two datas. **SOS Matrix** and **Scale Values**. Then I read the file in python and got the SOS matrix and filtered my signal using the result as follows ([using `scipy.sosfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt.html))

```
from scipy import signal

x_sos = signal.sosfilt(sos, x)  # x is my signal
```

The result I get has the desired shape except for the amplitude being different (I applied the same filter in Matlab and compared the output from the python code). I understand that scale values needs to come into this equation. But how do I incorporate that? I don't understand [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13051/matlab-sos-filter-in-c#answers-header). [This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36015/whats-the-point-of-matlabs-scaling-array-for-secord-order-section-filters) has answers explaining the scale values but still I have no idea how I should use that in the python code

---

**EDIT:** (After getting the answer) To anyone who is interested in the final code, here it is. And there's an explanation again in [this thread](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/230948-sos-filter-how-to-manually-apply-scale-values)

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

x_sos = signal.sosfilt(sos, x) * np.prod(scale)  # x is my signal
```

Comment: Hmm... by documentations, Matlab:sosfilt returns sos coefficients in matrix format ... signal:sosfilt waits array type input for sos parameter... .

Comment: I am using the `filterDesigner` in matlab and exporting the dilter as ASCII file. [This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13051/matlab-sos-filter-in-c) has the format of the file if you're interested to take a look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale values should be all $1$ except for the first Unless that's $1$ too. Multiply your output signal with that first scale value OR multiply the first three numbers in the first three row of you SOS matrix with that number before filtering.

**EDIT**

Turns out the filter designer makes this more convoluted than it needs to be. Just multiply all the scale values and multiply output with the product.

Comment: But the matlab saved file has these scale values `0.096,0.089,0.083,0.078,0.074,0.070,0.068,0.066,0.064,0.063,0.063`. I have these comments in it `% Filter Structure    : Direct-Form II, Second-Order Sections                                    
% Number of Sections  : 11                                                                       
% Stable              : Yes                                                                      
% Linear Phase        : No `